# Python Flask App: how to access container environment variables inside java script file

Tags: javascript, flask

i'm programming a python flask app which has some java script files. There are some environment variables that were defined when the container is deployed to kurbenetes. How to access this variables for a java script file inside an flask application ?

In Python it would be with `os.environ['Variable'] = 'some_value'`. How about javascript ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are several viable solutions, but I would use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

So basically you render the variables via your templates as HTML, and then access them in your JavaScript.

Example from the linked article

```
<article
  id="electric-cars"
  data-columns="3"
  data-index-number="12314"
  data-parent="cars">
...
</article>
```

And then you'd access the element and its attributes via JavaScript.

As an alternative, you could generate the JavaScript code from your backend.

As a third way, you could call your backend via http from your JavaScript code.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mentioned that these environments variables does not come from html. They are container environment variables that are created when the container is deployed

Comment: Right - I got you :-) Your Python code reads the environment data, and then you can apply one of the three options form above. e.g. a browser requests a page, your Flask / Python code reads the environment variables, passes them to your Jinja templates, and then Flask returns a rendered HTML with data attributes.